# High Resolution Webcam and Projector for Near-Blind Individual

Tags: webcam, projector

My father-in-law suffers from Retinitis Pigmentosa. It's an inherited disease of the retina where the rods and cones (the light sensing cells) on the periphery of your retina gradually start dying. Your field of vision gets narrower and narrower and narrower until you become blind.

We were at a treatment center yesterday for people with inherited retinal diseases, and one thing we saw was this setup where they used a camera to look down on something, like a newspaper, and display it on a large screen to give people the ability to read. It also did a lot of other things that for my father-in-law's case wasn't necessary. The device was very expensive and I was of the thought that I could put something together for cheaper.

I was hoping that someone could share some recommendations for webcams that I would mount on a little stand. Image quality is critical. 
His eyes get tired after looking at computer screens too so I was thinking about maybe using a projector to project the image on a nearby wall. I definitely don't know anything about projectors and could use some suggestions here too.

Thank you for any help,

mj